# How to unzip xxx.js.tar files

Tags: javascript, tar, unzip

Apologies if duplicated somewhere?

I can see a lot of posts about unzipping tar files but they get very technical and never quite seem to match what i need to do.

Using Peazip i have unzipped a xxx.js.tar.gp file and am left with an xxx.js.tar file.

How can i unzip the contents of that resultant file within Windows 7...If it is indeed possible?

I found this [Javascript TAR file](http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/extracting-the-contents-of-a-tar-file-in-javascript/) article which looked promising but when i browse for and select the file nothing else seems to happen?

Any ideas most welcome.

Comment: I think you can untar files with a number of tools, including [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Isn't a common tar file ? Which can be extracted using tar utility or other compression utilities like 7z or winrar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much do you know about the archive? Is it encrypted?
[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) unzips tar files. 
[gpg](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpg_002dzip.html) might help you if the file is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks all - easier than i thought just unzipping it with Peazip has done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinRAR to unpack tar files in Windows 7: http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm

Comment: Thanks for replies all - i don't think the files are encrypted so i'll try one of the suggestions and post back results.

Answer (score -1):

Tar is an archive itself, all you need is to extract it with 7-Zip or PeaZip.
As .tar format does not support compression it is usually zipped afterwards to reduce size for distribution, so you find it as .tar.gz, tar.bz. tar.xz etc., a compressed container containing the tar file where the actual content (the js files, in your example) is archived.
It takes two steps, but the extraction process works the same, with same tools.